# Windows 10 is really zoomed in

Tags: windows-10, zoom

I have just logged in to a Samsung Windows 10 laptop and it is zoomed in to the point where the icons do fit in the screen...

The screen pixel thing is on high and the zoom in magnifier is on 100% and cannot go lower.

Please help me, I have no idea what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Check your display resolution:

Windows 7: Right click on desktop -> click "Screen Resolution" and set it to Resolution that says Recommended next to it.

Windows 10: Right click on desktop -> Display Settings -> Advanced Display Settings -> "Resolution" drop-down box. Set to "Recommended".

If you only see very low options (like 640X480 or something in that range) you probably need to install graphics drivers.

Comment: Please try to add some spacing to your answers to make it easier to read

Comment: I right clicked on the desktop and It did not say screen resolution in the thingie

Comment: Sorry, I was on a Windows 7 machine. For Windows 10: Right click -> Display Settings -> Advanced Display Settings -> "Resolution" drop-down box